# Dottie number and prime factorization

Tags: prime-factorization, constants

It's related to Dottie number and prime factorization .

Let :

$D=\operatorname{Dottie-number}\simeq 0.7390851332$

Now define $n\geq 3$ an integer:

$$\lfloor\left(D\right)^{-2n}\rfloor=P$$

Then it seems that the prime factorization is write as for example :

$$97636=2^2×7×11×317,75566970=2×3^2×5×839633$$

**So I conjecture that the prime factorization of $P$ is composed with one prime with a power less than it self and other prime with power equal to zero or one .**

It have some similarity with another question of mine with $n!+1$

**Added after lulu's answer :**

Can you give a counter-example if the last digit o $P$ is not even i.e $(0,2,4,6,8)$ ?

Some example at $n=29$ to $n=50$

1)$n=29$ last digit $8$ exclude

2)$n=30$ last digit is $0$ exclude

3)$n=31$ $138338505 = 3^2×5×3074189$ OK

4)$n=32$ $253252735 = 5×50650547$ OK

5)$n=33$ $463623255 = 3^2×5×71×145109$ OK

6)$n=34$ the last digit is $4$ exclude

7)$n=35$ the last digit is a $8$ exclude

8)$n=36$ $2844450715 = 5×421×1351283$ OK

9)$n=37$ the last digit is zero $exclude$

10)$n=38$ $9532801445 = 5×877×2173957$ OK

11)$n=39$ $17451453903 = 3×13×6637×67421$ OK

12)$n=40$ $31947926857 = 7×11×3461×119881$ OK

13)$n=41$ $58486246255 = 5×31×19423×19427$ OK

14)$n=42$ $107069263563 = 3×35689754521$ OK

15)$n=43$ last digit is a $4$ exclude

16)$n=44$ $358828516513 = 211×12967×131149$ OK

17)$n=45$ last digit is a $2$ exclude

18)$n=46$ $1202566450709 = 13×199×4663×99689$ OK

19)$n=47$ $2201507405719 = 163741×13445059$ OK

20)$n=48$ $4030242864815 = 5×17×409×991×116981$

21)$n=49$ $7378061734971 = 3^2×819784637219$ near a counter-example but OK

22)$n=50$ $13506827452083 = 3^2×7×21221×10102921$ near a counter-exmple but OK

Question :

Can you (dis)prove the conjecture ?

Reference :

[An exact series expansion for the Dottie number](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2303.17962.pdf)

Comment: What conjecture?  The factoring of $\lfloor D^{-2n}\rfloor$?  Why do you believe it might be true?  How many $n$ have you checked it for?

Comment: Just playing with it, I get $P_{12}$  (so $n=12$) as $1416=2^3\times 3\times 59$, which seems like a counterexample, no?

Comment: And $P_{28}$ (so $n=28$) is $22548096 = 2^7\times 3^2\times 23^2\times 37$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the benefit of those unfamiliar with the term, "the Dottie Number" refers to the real solution of $\cos x = x$.

The numerical remark seems like just an accident of small numbers.  Many instances occur where $P_n=\lfloor D^{-2n}\rfloor$ is divisible by $2^2$ or $3^3$.  And $$P_{28}=\big \lfloor D^{-56}\big \rfloor =22548096 = 2^7\times 3^2\times 23^2\times 37$$

see [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=factor+floor%280.7390851332151606416553120876738734040134%5E-56%29)

Comment: I agree so can you propose a conjecture ?

Comment: Why?  Is there any reason to imagine that this sequence has other than generic factoring patterns?

Comment: OK but your example is just composed with $2,3,7$ which is the start of something.

Comment: it seems the conjecture is true if the last digit is not $2,4,6,8,0$

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=factor+floor%28%280.7390851332151606416553120876738734040134117589007574649656806357%29%5E%28-78%29%29

Comment: Absent a solid heuristic, I don't see the point.  Excluding those last digits just means you are excluding $2$ is a factor.  Well, "most" numbers are square free anyway, and if you remove $2$ as a factor and allow some small exponents, you get a whole lot more.  In any case, I suggest doing a deep search.  Look at the first few thousand values of $n$.  Then do the statistical work to see whether the results you get are improbable under sensible assumptions or not.

Comment: Added something to $n=100$ it seems true .

Comment: Can you explain what '**one prime with a power less than it self and other prime with power equal to zero or one**' means please.

Comment: @PeterPhipps  Was that addressed to me or to the OP?  If to me, I took it to mean that, in the prime factorization of $P_{2n}=\prod p_i^{a_i}$ we might have one $a_i$ bigger than $1$, but it would then be small ($<p_i$, say) and then all the other $a_j$ were $1$.  As my example shows, this claim does not always hold.  Of course, that doesn't prove that some similar claim might not hold.

Comment: @lulu It was addressed to the OP but your explanation is clear so thank you.